# Python and integer representation (leading zeros issue)

Tags: python, numpy, integer, binaryfiles

This is similar to a question asked on the programming Stack Exchange: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/158247/binary-representation-in-python-and-keeping-leading-zeros

Essentially, I have some numbers that I keep track of in hex:

```
SOME_NUMBERS = (0xAABBCCDDEEFF, 0xAA55AA55AA55, 0xBEEF0000BEEF)
```

However, Python tries to outsmart me and over-thinks, so when I write the value to a file, I get this in my hex editor:

```
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 AA BB CC DD EE FF
```

It looks to me that Python stores and writes my 48-bit number as a 64- or 128-bit number.  How could I prevent the leading zeroes from being written to the file?  By comparison, when using `numpy.random.bytes(6)`, Python will write the values to the file without leading zeroes, so it should be capable of doing this I think.  Thoughts?

Comment: How are you `pack`ing the data and writing to the file?

Comment: Please show your code, we (usually) can't guess the issue blindly.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_data_type#Integer_numbers On a 64-bit platform, Python will store `0xAABBCCDDEEFF` in memory as a 64-bit integer (just as `0x1` or even `0x0` would be), so when you write it out you'll get 64 bits, unless you explicitly pack the individual bytes yourself.

Answer (score 2):

The critical thing is how you are packing the numbers.  You can write single bytes - it is unusual for a number format to be 6 bytes. I found the following to work for one of the values:

```
import struct

outfile = 'output.dat'
fh = open(outfile, "wb")

var = struct.pack('6B', 0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC, 0xDD, 0xEE, 0xFF)

fh.write(var)
fh.close()
```

If you use other types, like a short, int, or long (or combinations thereof) you might run into endian issues.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a 48-bit binary value written to a file, you'll have to write 6 bytes yourself. There's no native number format of that length. Use the `struct` module to convert a value to bytes:

```
packed = struct.pack('>q', value) # 64 bits (8 bytes)
f.write(packed[-6:])
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix my issue, I had to do two things:

1) Switch to Python 3
2) Use int.to_bytes()

```
f = open(fileName, 'wb')
for d in dataBuffer:
    if type(d) == int:
         f.write(d.to_bytes(6, byteorder='big'))
    else:
         f.write(d)
    f.close()
```

I couldn't use struct.pack() or the numpy.savetext(), as I needed to handle 10,000 random values for 2000 files.  This seemed easier, but I also had to make my code work with Python 3.  I've learned that Python, while trying to be smart and do things for the user, ends up making a mess of things and increasing frustration levels.

Comment: Nice!  I didn't know python 3 had this.

Otoh, shouting at the hammer you struck your thumb with may feel like a relief, but isn't really going to help you.  If I learnt anything from this kind of problems, it's that my own assumptions are always to be questioned.  But maybe that's more of a thing for programmers.stackexchange.com :)

Answer (score 0):

You could save as text using `np.savetxt`:

```
import numpy as np
sn = np.array([0xAABBCCDDEEFF, 0xAA55AA55AA55, 0xBEEF0000BEEF])
np.savetxt('testfile',sn,'0x%X')
```

or

```
np.savetxt('testfile',sn,'%X') # without the '0x'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `struct.pack`, you can write the bytes individually to file by masking out successive bytes of the source integer and using `chr` to convert them to byte strings :

```
for shift in range(40, -1, -8):
    f.write(chr((d >> shift) & 0xff))
```

But this is basically what `struct.pack` is doing for you under the hood (and in C), so you'd be better off not reinventing the wheel.